# operations on Multiple-key Data structure

Tags: java

[image]

My requirement is to create above mentioned data structure.

I expect following operations on this data structure.

Operation 1 :

```
public Set<Subscriber> retrievedSetofSubscribers(eventName, RegionID, RegionName);
```

It means when I provide `EventName`, `RegionID` and `RegionName`  (multiple keys),  operation should return a list of subscribers.

Operation 2 :

```
public void InsertIntoTable(eventName, regionID, String RegionName, Subscriber);
```

Is there any Java supported API is available for above mentioned operations?

Comment: You should consider going back through your [asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1223964/pankesh-patel?tab=questions) and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) that solved your problems.

Comment: thanks assylias, I have done .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that represents one row of this table.

Then the whole table is a Map with 'key' being EventName and 'value' being the row class.

No multi-key needed!

Comment: Let me rephrase it again Operation 2: InsertIntoTable(eventName, regionID, String RegionName, Subscriber); is invoked by different objects.

Comment: @PankeshPatel: it's also easy: `RowClass new_row = new RowClass(regionID, RegionName, subscriber); the_table.add(eventName, new_row)`.